# Python equivalent of php's virtual()

Tags: php, python, virtual, equivalent

Do you know if there is a python equivalent of php's [**`virtual()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) ?

My configuration is python, djanogo, mod_wsgi, apache

Trying to include a script that has only examples for php using the above include and also needs to be included in all website's pages.

Thanks

LE: I'm including a .cgi script

Comment: Could you make a CURL request to localhost instead?

Comment: Why you couldn't just include the files the common way (`include 'file.php';`)?

Comment: @agf: He is looking for a python- _equivalent_ of _PHPs_ `virtual()`. I were curious, why he wants to use `virtual()` or something like `virtual()` at all, if one can use `include()`, or -- because he mentioned the cgi-script now -- (e.g.) `exec()`. `virtual()` is a) a Apache-only feature and b) fires an additional request. Without good reasons its just overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reference to this I see is

```
http://www.modpython.org/pipermail/mod_python/2004-January/014834.html
```

Which states `In theroy you can use the Apache 2.x chain handlers feature, where more
than one content handler can process the request.  I say in theroy
because I've read about it, but never tried it =)`

From the PHP Manual, `virtual() is an Apache-specific function which is similar to <!--#include virtual...--> in mod_include. It performs an Apache sub-request . . . This function is only supported when PHP is installed as an Apache module.`

Here is the link for info about Apache Filters, which is what is meant by "chain handling":

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/filter.html

The document should be able to be processed by `mod_include` after it's output from `mod_wsgi` (or before, if that's what you want).